# Use UserManager GenerateUserTokenAsync to create custom tokens with extra data

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-identity, usermanager

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and I need to generate custom tokens in my application.

Asp.Net Core Identity UserManager can generate classic tokens like EmailVerification, ...

But it has also a method to generate tokens with different purposes ([MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.generateusertokenasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2)):

```
public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GenerateUserTokenAsync (TUser user, string tokenProvider, string purpose);
```

I need to generate a token with the following information:

1. Purpose = AddUserToProject
2. User = A given user
3. ProjectId = The Project Id to which the User should be added.
4. RoleId = The Role Id of the User in the Project

On GenerateUserTokenAsync I can add the User and the Purpose ...

But I'm not sure how to add (3) and (4) e.g. ProjectId and RoleId.

And how can I retrieve it later so I can actually perform the action.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom token provider, and then instruct ASP.NET Core to use that. Create a class that implements `IUserTokenProvider<TUser, TKey>`. Then, you can either explicitly use it:

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "MyCustomTokenProvider", purpose);
```

Or you can sub it in for any or all of the Identity token providers in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(o => {
    o.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = nameof(MyCustomTokenProvider);
    // rinse and repeat for other token providers you want to change
    // see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#tokens
})
.AddTokenProvider<MyCustomTokenProvider>(nameof(MyCustomTokenProvider));
```

[1]:

Comment: I know I can create a custom provider but my problem is how to create one for the particular case I posted. Does the token includes the extra info and then I retrieve it? Or so I save the info in the database along with the token to later retrieve that info? I am sending the token by email so when the user clicks the link I need to check if the token is valid for that purpose and somehow use the UserId, ProjectId and RoleId to perform the action.

Comment: The interface requires  `GenerateAsync` and `ValidateAsync` methods. That's where you would define how the token is created and then how it's validated. You simply want to inject a data protection provider so that you can encrypt and decrypt. The unencrypted token can be whatever you want.